# How to print new output at top of terminal in python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, printing, terminal

How could I go about printing the latest output at the top of the terminal so instead of new output being constantly added to the bottom of the window, it is stacked on the top?

Example program:

```
for x in range(4):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Desired output:

```
3
2
1
0
```

Edit:
The example is just a simple visual to understand the question better. My actual programs will be returning data in real time, which I am interested in having the latest printed to the top if that makes sense.

Comment: Why can't you start printing from `3` and go to `0`?

Comment: It's possible using things like ANSII escape codes, but they're a bit of a pain to deal with. Ya, just printing backwards would make a lot more sense here.

Comment: @SayandipDutta The example is just a simple visual to understand the question better. My actual programs will be returning data in real time, which I am interested in having the latest printed to the top if that makes sense.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The example is just a simple visual to understand the question better. My actual programs will be returning data in real time, which I am interested in having the latest printed to the top if that makes sense

Comment: @mattwatkins Ya, look into ANSII escape codes, or a library that delegates to them like pycurses. It will complicate your code a bit though, so make sure you actually need this.

Comment: I see, I will check.

Comment: That method will let you change where the cursor is, so you can move the cursor back up to the top of the screen, and "redraw" the data. You could also just print a ton of newlines then redraw it all, but that looks bad a lot of the time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate will see what I can find. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using ANSII Escape Code to Move Cursor

One way would be keep printing appropriate number of `go-up-to-beginnig` ANSII Escape Characters for each line, but that means, you will need to store the items in each iteration:

```
historical_output = []
padding = -1
UP = '\033[F'

for up_count, x in enumerate(range(4), start=1):
    curr_len = len(str(x))

    if curr_len > padding:
        padding = curr_len

    historical_output.insert(0, x)
    print(UP * up_count)
    print(*historical_output, sep='\n'.rjust(padding))
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
0
```

---

### Restricting the Output to Certain Number of Lines

If you want to restrict the output to last `n` lines, you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

max_lines_to_display = 5        # If this is None, falls back to above code
historical_output = deque(maxlen=max_lines_to_display)
padding = -1
up_count = 1
UP = '\033[F'

for x in range(12):
    curr_len = len(str(x))

    if curr_len > padding:
        padding = curr_len

    historical_output.appendleft(x)
    print(UP * up_count)

    if (max_lines_to_display is None 
        or up_count < max_lines_to_display+1):
        up_count += 1

    print(*historical_output, sep='\n'.rjust(padding))
```

Output:

```
11
10
9
8
7
```

---

`\033[F` is an `ANSII Escape Code` that moves the cursor to the start of the previous line.

**NOTE:**

- This does not work on all types of terminals, but will work on windows `cmd` (as I see in your tags).
- If you need to use `while` instead of `for` keep a counter variable `up_count=1` and increase it at the end of each iteration.
- This approach is fine for limited amount of lines, but if you want to go on forever, you should use something along the lines of `curses`.

Comment: This works perfect, Thanks! Would you happen to know if its possible to disable the autoscroll on cmd so it doesnt scroll down as new items go through the bottom of the window? If not its no big deal, the solution will work perfect as is.

Comment: Could be useful: https://superuser.com/q/1273370/1095137

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this

```
for x in list(range(4))[::-1]:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot inverse the terminal order easily.

But with `python` you can use this:

```py
for i in reversed(range(10)):
    print(i)
```

```sh
# Output
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah the terminal order is what I am aiming for. I edited to question to make it a little clearer.